# navigation prop is undefined (React Navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am simply trying to learn React Navigation. I installed packages below;

```
expo install react-navigation react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screen
```

Then I am trying to put a button and navigate with it but

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Example')}
```

My project does not recognize "navigation" after "props" ? I installed all packages still same

app.js file:

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Chat from './screens/Chat.js';
import Home from './screens/Home.js'

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: Home,
  Chat: Chat
});
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
export default AppContainer;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is this code in functional component?

Comment: No its normal react component @KishanBharda

Comment: I created a new screen, and tried to navigate that from app.js default component. I followed one tutorial which is blank react native project with nothing, trainer can write this.props.navigation.navigate and I cant  @TrueTiem

Comment: @ugrdursun app.js doesnt have navigation prop. only screens. You can use navigation prop in your screen component. But if you want to use it in app.js you have 'NavigationActions' (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html)

Comment: I've found a tutorial for expo and react-navigation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QhxKJlMD4g (he is using react-navigation v2 which you dont export createAppContainer. But you must use it with v3 and v4.)

Comment: Can you post some code? there's a lot missing here. Where are you definyning app contaier? Where is your navigator structure? Is the button inside one of the screens you defined inside your navigator?

Comment: @TrueTiem I used app container now, however in home screen component still cant type this.props.navigation ? And I did not understand how does react releases is it component or a screen which I want to navigate

Comment: @Auticcat i edited the post with my app.js, Button is in Home.js in Home react component (as default)